# Unexpected result from `in` operator - Python

Tags: python

```
>>> item = 2
>>> seq = [1,2,3]
>>> print (item in seq)
True
>>> print (item in seq is True)
False
```

Why does the second `print` statement output `False`?

Comment: It might be because of how python evaluates an expression. You might want to use `print ((item in seq) is True)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`in` and `is` are comparison operators in Python, the same in that respect as, say, `<` and `==`.  In general,

```
expr1 <comparison1> expr2 <comparison2> expr3
```

is treated as

```
(expr1 <comparison1> expr2) and (expr2 <comparison2> expr3)
```

except that `expr2` is evaluated only once.  That's why, e.g.,

```
0 <= i < n
```

works as expected.  However, it applies to *any* chained comparison operators.  In your example,

```
item in seq is True
```

is treated as

```
(item in seq) and (seq is True)
```

The `seq is True` part is False, so the whole expression is False.  To get what you probably intended, use parentheses to change the grouping:

```
print((item in seq) is True)
```

[Click here for the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

Answer (score 3):

Your statement `item in seq is True` is internally evaluated as `(item in seq) and (seq is True)` as shown below

```
>>>print ((item in seq) and (seq is True))
False
```

(seq is True) is False and therefore your statement outputs False.

Comment: Isn't that explained sufficiently in @Tim Peters answer?

Comment: @t.m.adam - We both answered more or less at the same time. If his answer explains this in more detailed way, let me delete this answer.

Comment: @Beginner NO. Can't a question have two correct answers?

Comment: @Beginner I don't see any harm in leaving your answer. Although you shouldn't lose the rep you gained for this question, if you delete.

Comment: Please don't take my comment the wrong way. I just wanted to encourage you to improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer below is not correct. The comment explains it an i verified:

```
In [17]: item in (seq is True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-4e7d6b2332d7> in <module>()
----> 1 item in (seq is True)
```

TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable

---

Previous answer
I believe it is evaluating `seq is True` (which evaluates to the bool `False`), then evaluating `item in False` (which evaluates to `False`).

Presumably you mean `print (item in seq) is True` (which evaluates to `True`)?

Comment: `item in False` raises a `TypeError`, as the right-hand value must be an iterable, which `False` is not.

Comment: changed answer. thanks