# Odd behaviour: What does "12 in [12,13,14] == True" mean in Python

Tags: python

I would have expected it to either have parenthesis to the left or to the right.

But it seems to do something else!

```
>>> 12 in [12,13,14] == True
False
>>> (12 in [12,13,13]) == True
True
>>> 12 in ([12,13,14] == True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

Comment: you're evaluating whether the integer 12 is in a boolean object. not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python operator precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328355/python-operator-precedence)

Comment: I admit I'm a little surprised about `12 in [12,13,14] == True` being False. If `in` comes before `==`, then I'd except the result to be True. If `in` comes after `==`, I'd expect it to be a syntax error. What's the difference between the first and second expressions?

Comment: The first expression is `(12 in [12,13,14]) and ([12,13,14] == True)` and the second group is `False`. What make it even more interesting ist that `if [12,13,14]` evaluates to `True`

Comment: @FrancescoMontesanon I can't see how the first expression would be `(12 in [12,13,14]) and ([12,13,14] == True)`. I'd think it would be identical to the second expression.

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano yes, it is clear from the actual list with `None` in place of `print`. Which clearly shows the list is evaluated first. Thank you.

Comment: @KirkStrauser: the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) and @Epsi95 answer shows that this is what python does. When I rewrite the expression as above I get a `False`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected result from \`in\` operator - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180899/unexpected-result-from-in-operator-python)

Comment: @PéterLeéh That's not an ideal duplicate cause it primarily talks about operators that *don't* chain. I suggested a more exact duplicate above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That the following expression evaluates to False may be surprising:

```
12 in [12,13,14] == True
```

Here's what's happening: the `in` and `==` operators have the same precedence,
and they support left-to-right **chaining** (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)), so
the expression is equivalent to

```
12 in [12,13,14] and [12,13,14] == True
```

Now `and` is less binding, and the left-hand side obviously evaluates to
`True`. Now for the tricky part: a non-empty sequence, such as the [12, 13, 14]
list **evaluates** to `True`, but it is not **equal** to `True`. It's a so-called
"truthy" value. Truthy and Falsy values are not booleans (not instances of type bool), but they
evaluate to either `True` or `False`.

So they right-hand side of the `and` comparison evaluates to `False`.

Comment: But I am curious about truthy value thing. Since `[12,13,14] == True` here it will only be true if both are list and the list elements arr equal. How does the truthly value thing comes into picture?

Comment: Or it could be true if both were boolean, and had the same boolean value. But the reality is, one is a list, the other a boolean, so it will never be true.

Comment: "truthy" means will evaluate to true in a Boolean context (as the condition in an if), even it may return a different type (such as non-empty list) in a different context.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about the first one i.e.

```py
12 in [12,13,14] == True
```

Since it was giving `False`. So I did a little analysis.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __eq__(self, other):
        print(other)
        return other == self.a

12 in [12, print('I am in list'), 14] == A(True)
```

It prints

```
I am in list
[12, None, 14]
False
```

That means:

1. `12 in [12, None, 14]` is checked which gives `True` (where `None` is the return value of `print()`)
2. An equality is checked between `[12, None, 14]` and `True`

Comment: That `print()` is a red herring. It's evaluated before anything else is, so you could just substitute its return value, `None`.